# Get the localPosition in onPan property of GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create match-the following using flutter. I got the source from which the swiping action started by the `onPanStart` property of `GestureDetector` by accessing the `details.localPosition`.

I need to find the destination point as well. But the `onPanEnd` property does not have `details.localPosition`.

How can I find the destination point? That is, where my swiping action stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property to find the `localPosition` in the `onPanEnd` parameter.

Instead declare a local variable in the class. Update the with `details.localPosition` inside `onPanUpdate` parameter.

Clearly when it ends, the variable contains the last updated value.